# How to add UITabBarItem to UITabBar

Tags: ios, swift, uitabbar

The following is part of my BaseViewController

```
class BaseViewController: UIViewController,MenuProtocol {

//DECLARE Control Objects
var MyTabBar:UITabBar = UITabBar()
```

In the viewDidLoad I add MyTabBar to the subview with it constraints

However I fail to add TabBarItems on it.

```
func MyCreateAndPlaceTabBarItems(){
    if MyTabBarStringArray.count == 0 {
        return
    }

    var count = 0

    for item in MyTabBarStringArray{

        let  tabItem = UITabBarItem(title: item, image: nil, tag: count)
        tabItem.badgeColor = .orange
        MyTabBar.items?.append(tabItem)

        count = count + 1
    }
}
```

[image]

The Navy Blue part is MyTabBar.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1):

i just run your code and found that after adding the image i can see the UITabBarItem

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {


@IBOutlet var MyTabBar: UITabBar!
var MyTabBarStringArray = [String]()
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    MyTabBarStringArray = ["a","d","e"]
    self.MyCreateAndPlaceTabBarItems()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

func MyCreateAndPlaceTabBarItems(){
    if MyTabBarStringArray.count == 0 {
        return
    }

    var count = 0

    for item in MyTabBarStringArray{

        let  tabItem = UITabBarItem(title: item, image: UIImage.init(named: "IconPinPoint"), tag: count)
        tabItem.badgeColor = .orange
        MyTabBar.items?.append(tabItem)
        count = count + 1
    }
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


}
```